# Fragment View Return Null

Tags: java, android

My view has been returning null even though i have set the view as a global variable and calling the findViewById on the onCreateView().

This are my codes for the view part

```
public class MainMenu extends Fragment {
TextView txt = null;
View view1;
View mView;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);
    mView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, null,false);
    pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
    twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(pref.getString("CONSUMER_KEY", ""), pref.getString("CONSUMER_SECRET", ""));
    txt = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tww1);


    //run retrieve tweets method
    new TweetStream().execute();

    new Thread(new MainMenu().new Consumer()).start();

    return mView;
}
```

In my fragment_main_menu.xml

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tww1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="100dp"
                android:text="OFF"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

and the codes that invoke it:

```
public void turnOn(){
txt.setText("ON");
}
```

the method which runs the turnOn function:

```
 class Consumer implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            while (queue.size() != 0) {
                String msg = getObj.getMsg();
                String[] result = msg.split("\\s");
                String msg2 = result[0];
                if(msg2.equals("ON")){
                    txt.setText("ON");
                    //turnOn();
                }
                else if(msg.equals("OFF")){
                    txt.setText("OFF");
                   // turnOff();
                }

            }
            if (queue.size() == 0) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                run();
            }


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the error i get:

```
06-19 12:47:43.921    5213-9586/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-128222
Process: com.example.john.fabric, PID: 5213
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Edit1: I am using false for the inflater inflate method. I do not see why i should get a null pointer.

Edit2: Running turnOn or setText method inside both return me null.

Comment: where you called `turnOn()` ? and post all code properly

Comment: from where you started thread?

Comment: Hi @KrishnaV Added! Its at the onCreateView

Comment: provide MainMenu class also.

Comment: post your complete code....

Comment: @RajSharma all these are under the same mainmenu class.

Comment: @KrishnaV done. MainMenu is the main class for all the methods below

Comment: replace new MainMenu().new Consumer() with new Consumer(). don't create MainMenu object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use runonUi thread to update values to UI part try below code

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            while (queue.size() != 0) {
                String msg = getObj.getMsg();
                String[] result = msg.split("\\s");
                String msg2 = result[0];

          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                if(msg2.equals("ON")){
                    txt.setText("ON");
                    //turnOn();
                }
                else if(msg.equals("OFF")){
                    txt.setText("OFF");
                   // turnOff();
                }
              }
             }
            }
            if (queue.size() == 0) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                run();
            }


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to inflate layout and then check

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);
    txt = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.tww1);
    new Thread(new Consumer()).start();
    return view1;
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            while (queue.size() != 0) {
                String msg = getObj.getMsg();
                String[] result = msg.split("\\s");
                String msg2 = result[0];
                if (msg2.equals("ON")) {
                    turnOn();
                } else{
                    txt.setText("OFF");
                    // turnOff();
                }

            }
            if (queue.size() == 0) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                run();
            }


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public void turnOn(){
    txt.setText("ON");
}
```

Comment: Hi @anand, Im still getting null .

Comment: `if(msg2.equals("ON")){
                    txt.setText("ON"); // Remove this 
                    turnOn();
                }`

Comment: Even i use turnOn() or txt.setText it will return me null

Comment: Isn't this the same as the one i originally posted using inflater.inflate false?